# Commutativity in 2 dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A,B are two matrices of order $2\times 2$ then prove that $(AB-BA)(AB-BA)$ commutes with any $2\times 2$ matrix. Please also comment on $why$ this is true and why this is not true for matrices of order $n\times n$ where $n$ is greater than $2$ .

(Consider the matrices as the linear transformations on a $2$ dimensional vector space and their product as, of course, the composition. I really need to get the picture in terms of transformations and their composition or something like that. One of the reason being that, perhaps then it would be easier to figure out why the generalisation doesn't work for n>2)

Comment: Randomly choose $A,B$.

Comment: It has not been stated, but this is not generally true for matrices of size $3 \times 3$ and bigger.  Following Olivier's statement, we can find matrices $A,B$ such that
$$
AB - BA =
\pmatrix{
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0
}
$$

Comment: Given that it is not true for larger matrices, the proof for the $2\times 2$ case is bound to use some computation that explicitly involves the size of the matrices; there is not going to be much of a conceptual explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to the original question.** This is false, you can produce any trace $0$ matrix that way, and any matrix is a trace $0$ matrix plus some multiple of the identity. If what you wrote were correct, it would imply that the matrix ring is commutative.

**Answer to the edited question.** It becomes true for $2\times 2$ matrices once you square them. Indeed, $2\times 2$ matrices have very simple caracteristic polynomials
$$X^2-\mathrm{Tr}(A)X+\det(A)$$
and so the square of a traceless $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ is equal to $-\det(A)\,I_2$ which indeed commutes to everything.

**Why it should work.** The fact of the matter is that a linear transformation that has trace $0$ admits a basis wherein its matrix has zeros along the diagonal (this is true for all $n\times n$ matrices over a field of characteristic $0$, it's a standard exercise, one reasons by induction over $n$). Geometrically, and in dimension $2$, this means that there exists a basis $(\vec{e},\vec{f})$ of the ($2$-dimensional) vector space $V$ wherein the linear transform $u$ (nonzero and with trace $0$) acts as follows
$$u(\vec{e})=\vec{f},\quad u(\vec{f})=b\vec{e}$$
for some real number $b$. This can be interpreted geometrically very easily: $u$ basically exchanges $\Bbb R\vec{e}$ and $\Bbb R\vec{f}$ (squishing the line $\Bbb R\vec{f}$ to a point if $b=0$). Now it is obvious that applying $u$ twice results in the homothecy of factor $b$.

Comment: Ah sorry.It was squared.

Comment: Can you suggest some way to do this without invoking traces and characteristic polynomials. I mean, I found this problem in Halmos' FDVS in the 'Matrices of Transformation' section and I haven't encountered these concepts yet.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom what about it?

Comment: I thought I had a counterexample for a second. Never mind.

Comment: @quarkine show that a commutator $AB-BA$ has diagonal terms that add up to $0$, and then show that the square of any matrix $C$ with this property $$C=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$$ is proportional to the identity matrix by hand calculation (you should get $C^2=(bc-a^2)\,I_2$).

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Well I guessed that a matrix that should commute with every other should be something of the form aI where a is some scalar and I identity.And a brute force calculation as you suggested does that. That works but doesn't answer the why. Sorry for asking again but I really need to get the picture in terms of transformations and their composition or something like that. And then it would be easier to figure out why the generalisation doesn't work for n>2, I suppose.